# How to read and understand the .hcc file with Python?

Tags: python, file

I am having a `.hcc` file, which I am trying to read but I am getting error.
This is what I am tried:

```
chardetect 2016.hcc
2016.hcc: windows-1253 with confidence 0.2724130248827703
```

I have tried the following:

```
>>> with open("2016.hcc","r",encoding="windows-1253") as f:
...     print(f.read())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1253.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 232: character maps to <undefined>
```

then I tried this without using encoding:

```
>>> with open("2016.hcc","r") as f:
...     print(f.read())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 284: character maps to <undefined>
```

After opening the file in byte mode, I was able to read but none was understandable.

Here is the sample file: [2016.hcc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tPR5KMfJlRwVvdwxMXaCO1zL1PtFaNub/view?usp=sharing)

Please let me know how I can do that.

**UPDATED ATTEMPT: **

```
>>> with open("2016.hcc","r",encoding="utf-16") as f:
...     print(f.read())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 61, in _buffer_decode
    codecs.utf_16_ex_decode(input, errors, 0, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 15390-15391: illegal encoding
```

Comment: It looks like this is [utf-16 LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) however, the format itself looks weird

Comment: I tried using the utf-16 LE . but it did not work. I will update question with the attempt I made.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8003/need-ideas-to-reverse-engineer-this-hcc-file-format

Comment: Sorry but I know nothing about this file format, it has UTF-16 LE BOM at the beginning but the rest of the format is not readable, if it's some proprietary format then you will need the correct reader